# How to insert data in sql server table using user defined table types, and check duplicate data?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am using C# to upload excel file data in sql server. I am creating a datatable and passing it to SP. I've created SP like below

```
    Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InsertData]

  @dt AS dbo.tbl_employees READONLY,
  @CREATEDBY as varchar(50),
  @folderPath as nvarchar(3000),
  @result as varchar(100) OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN
 

 INSERT INTO Employees(Name, Email, Branch, CreatedBy, FolderPath)
  SELECT Name, Email, Branch,@CREATEDBY, @folderPath
  FROM @dt; 
set @result='Success';


select @result
Print @result
END
```

But it's not giving me output value. Also I want to validate duplicate data from user-defined-table(dbo.tbl_employees) with actual table (Employees). If there are any duplicate data then it should give a message 'Duplicate data'. Don't know how to do it. Can someone help me to make it work?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by it's "not giving you output value" exactly? `SELECT`ing, `PRINT` and returning the value of `@result` as an `OUTPUT` parameter seems some what pointless; just do one if you *must*. If you want to know a procedure succeeded then use `RETURN` codes (`0` for success, anything else for failure, often denoting an error number).

Comment: Thanks @ThomA but I want to have 3 different outputs like in case of Success it should print 'Sucess', if user is trying to insert duplicate data then Return should be 'Duplicate data', if there are some special characters in uploaded data then Return should be 'Dirty data'. So that I can give actual message to user based on these returns.

Comment: *None* of the logic is in your question, @Vikas ... You just `SET` the value of `@result` to be `'Success'`; why would you expect the value of `@result` to be anything else..?

Comment: *"if there are some special characters in uploaded data then..."* This sounds like application logic to me. You should be validating your data doesn't have any "special characters" there. Alternatively, you could use a `CHECK` `CONSTRAINT`, tbut that will cause an error, which you could then consume in your application to denote the data is "dirty".

Comment: @ThomA, agree those logic is currently not present in SP because I don't know how to validate the duplicate data using 'User-Define-Table' value, hence looking for help to validate the data.

Comment: do you want to insert any data if there's duplicate? or reject everything. the logic will vary a lot depending on what you want exactly. do you want to return details of errors for each row or just a generic "duplicate exists"

Comment: If you don't want your table to allow duplicate values, then create a `UNIQUE` `CONSTRAINT` on the table. If you want to not allow duplicate values in the table type parameter, create a `UNIQUE` `INDEX` on the type (you'll need to `DROP` and re`CREATE` the `TYPE` to do that); despite what the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) says it appears that they don't support `CONSTRAINT`s.

Comment: You, however, need to [edit] your question to properly explain the logic. The fact that the comments contain crucial information about the problem doesn't help; the question needs to be complete and explain the *whole* problem. What does C# have to do with  the issue as well? Presumably, as you've tagged it, you *could* do that in your application layer instead, which seems a better option for at least some of this.

Comment: Can you expand on _But it's not giving me output value_. Where? in your C# code? Post it. In your database? Please explain clearly that you're not seeing expected data in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a unique constraint on your table to ensure you don't get duplicate data.

But if you want a special return value (rather than just throwing an error), you need to check your data first, and conditionally return a value.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.usp_InsertData
  @dt AS dbo.tbl_employees READONLY,
  @CREATEDBY as varchar(50),
  @folderPath as nvarchar(3000),
  @result as varchar(100) OUTPUT
AS

SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRAN;

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM Employees e WITH (HOLDLOCK)
    JOIN @dt dt ON dt.Name = e.Name
)
BEGIN
    SET @result = 'Duplicate data';
    ROLLBACK;
    RETURN;
END;

INSERT INTO Employees
    (Name, Email, Branch, CreatedBy, FolderPath)
SELECT Name, Email, Branch, @CREATEDBY, @folderPath
FROM @dt;

SET @result = 'Success';

COMMIT;
```

If you are having problems getting information out of an `OUTPUT` parameter in C# then that is a separate question. There are already many posts that show you how to do that.